# htaccess rewrite and remove .php extension

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, redirect

So, I have been reading up on mod_rewrite because I want to remove the .php extension and have the URL look different, so that the end user doesn't see all the arguments in the URL.

My goal:
    `/foo.php?p=bar`
Looks like:
    `/foo/bar`

Where foo and bar can be anything, numeric and chars.
I'm only working with .php files, so it doesn't have to work with .html and alike.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code in your `DOCUMENT_ROOT/.htaccess` file:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f
RewriteRule ^ - [F]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/?$ $1.php [L]

RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}/$1\.php -f [NC]
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/?$ $1.php?p=$2 [L]
```